# How to fill the violin plot on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I fill the violin in ggplot2?

Sample data

```
Ram2 <- structure(list(
    G = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                  levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    T = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
          4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my script

```
ggplot(Ram2, aes(x = G, y = T, 
                color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)]))+  
    geom_violin(alpha = 0.8, adjust=0.05)+
    scale_color_manual(values = c(WT = '#3CBEC3', at5g01950 = '#C3413C')) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    labs(color = '')
```

And here is my output

[image: Output]

I'd like to fill the violin with the same color as the outline.

Thank you

I use fill = "color" but it fill both variables with same color.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Help us to help you by [making this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(Ram2)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: structure(list(G = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    T = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 0):

We can add this to the global `aes()` to copy the evaluated color to the fill aesthetic:

```
ggplot(Ram2, aes(x = G, y = T, 
             color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)],
             fill = after_scale(colour)))+  
...
```

[image]